# Custom index name in South/Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-south

Is there a way to set our own index name in Django models?  Currently, the migration scripts would create a name in format `[table_name]_9fcb4ba3` and I'd like to have the name more descriptive, i.e. `[table_name]_[column_name]` or so.

On the Django's Model Field Reference page, it doesn't seem to have such option (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#db-index)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone finding its way from Google - seems Django 1.11 allows you now to have a custom name for indexes.  Following the documentation as described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/indexes/#name):

> **Index.name**
>
> The name of the index. If name isn’t provided Django will auto-generate a name. For compatibility with different databases, index names cannot be longer than 30 characters and shouldn’t start with a number (0-9) or underscore (_).

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of customizing the name for indexes as these are generated by hashing (the index name calculation uses some hashing techniques)